# use of unassigned local variable 'fn'

Tags: asp.net

```
Line 51: cmd.Parameters.Add("@bprc", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text);
Line 52: cmd.Parameters.Add("@bcat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
Line 53: cmd.Parameters.Add("@bimg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = fn;
Line 54: cmd.Parameters.Add("@bdsc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = TextBox6.Text;
Line 55: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: can you explain your problem?

Comment: Where is `fn` declared? Can you post that code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems, you have declared variable `fn` but did not initialize it. Debug, whether you really set any value to `fn`, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you declare a variable, but then don't assign it to anything.  For example if you had the following:

```
int myInt;
return Math.Min(0, myInt);
```

Then the compiler would report an error second line as you tried to use `myInt`, but you didn't give it a value.

Note that you will get this error even if only 1 *potential* path results in `myInt` not being set, for example:

```
bool myBool = true;
int myInt;
if (myBool)
{
    myInt = 1;
}
return Math.Min(0, myInt);
```

The solution is to initialise `fn` to some sensible value at some point before line 53, or ensure that it is set to some value for all possible code paths:

```
string fn = null; // (assuming `fn` is a string)
```